# DSE Graph with Java Driver, how to build a graph using Tinkerpop/Gremlin APIs like in Titan?

Tags: cassandra, gremlin, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, tinkerpop

I have an application which currently relies on tinkerpop & titan.
I would like to assess Graph features provided by DSE 5.0 but I did not find any way to instantiate a tinkerpop Graph using DSE Graph java API.

For titan, I used the tinkerpop GraphFactory class:

- org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph g = GraphFactory.open(configurationFile);
- The configuration file in parameter refers to the TitanFactory class which return an implementation of the tinkerpop Graph interface 
  (gremlin.graph=com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory)

Is there any equivalent in DSE Graph API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**April 28th 2017 update**

Now the graph fluent API functionality can be used through this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.dse</groupId>
    <artifactId>dse-java-driver-graph</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**October 28th 2016 update**

The first implementation of Gremlin fluent API is available even though it is still in beta (https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1250?focusedCommentId=35907&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-35907):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>dse-driver</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1-beta1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-dse-graph</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-beta1</version>
</dependency>
```

This is how it works today with a small example:

```
        DseCluster dseCluster = DseCluster.builder()
                .addContactPoint(HOST_IP)
                .build();
        DseSession dseSession = dseCluster.connect();
        GraphTraversalSource g = DseGraph.traversal(dseSession, new GraphOptions().setGraphName(GRAPH_NAME));

        GraphTraversal<Vertex,Vertex> gT = g.addV("User").property("uuid","testuuid");

        GraphStatement graphStatement =  DseGraph.statementFromTraversal(gT);
        GraphResultSet grs = dseSession.executeGraph(graphStatement.setGraphName(GRAPH_NAME));
        System.out.println(grs.one().asVertex());
```

**Original Post**

I was trying to migrate code from Titan to Datastax DSE..I was seeking the same APIs as you were so, I filed an issue in the github repository of java dse driver: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver-dse/issues/42

It is currently into works as a lot of coordination among different language platforms and optimization is going on.

> We do have plans for a more fluent api. Just as some background, most
>   of the TinkerPop/gremlin drivers out there do a String based approach
>   - that is, send the traversal String to the server, the server then optimizes the traversal and executes it. The result is sent back to
>   the client and is deserialized.
>
> For Titan, what people commonly use is remote server mode which gives
>   access to a Graph object. This is great from a development perspective
>   because it offers a fluent api which is compile time checked and can
>   be code completed. From a practical perspective, it's actually less
>   efficient because it's a remote server that has to make lots of round
>   trips to the underlying data store to execute the traversal. So the
>   current String based method is actually more efficient.
>
> We do see great value in a fluent api though. We're working on a
>   solution for that right now. It will likely take the form of
>   RemoteGraph so you'll have a graph object that is similar for
>   traversals. We're also working in the community on TINKERPOP-1278 to
>   make traversals much more idiomatic across languages. So the reason
>   why it's taking a bit of time to get this better experience is that
>   we're trying to make sure it's 1) done efficiently and 2) that it's
>   done correctly from the TinkerPop foundation up through DSE Graph.
>
> In conjunction with the RemoteGraph interface for traversals, we'll
>   have a fluent api to do updates.

You can have a look at the complete discussion and track the issue here: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver-dse/issues/42 (moved to Jira)

https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1250

Unfortunately you either need to stick with gremlin qraph queries for everything as a String or keep using Titan till Datastax DSE APIs are ready.

Comment: Issue link is broken https://github.com/datastax/java-driver-dse/issues/42

Comment: @Hadiaboumrad the issues were moved to jira and are not public anymore.. so it was deleted from github. Here are the links that are online: 
https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1250
https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1124